Unable to use software
Hi I am unable to use programs that I installed on Ubuntu Focal.  Including Wine.  The terminal says its the latest version, however I am unable to find it in my Applications folder.

You don't run wine directly, you run windows apps using it. Don't expect to see a menu item for wine.

Did you install it as a package or did you compile from source? Open up a terminal and type wine. What happens?

Also take a look at the wiki: https://wiki.winehq.org/Wine_User%27s_Guide#Using_Wine

This question is similar to: How can I install Windows software or games?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

One way to use Wine with a graphical interface is to use it thought Playonlinux. https://www.playonlinux.com/en/. It will also add application icons to your desktop.
